# How to make Xcode4 stop at NSAssert failure?

Tags: xcode4

Currently, my Xcode4 does not stop at `NSAssert` failure. How can I make it stop at `NSAssert` failure again?

Comment: You should accept the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6413735/377384

Answer (score 36, accepted):

1. Go to the XCode 4 breakpoint navigator.
2. Click the + button and choose "Add Symbolic Breakpoint"
3. Set Symbol: to "-[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:]"
4. Click "Done"

Now you will stop in the debugger as soon as NSAssert fires.  In my testing, it goes to the nearest source code and doesn't just show you the assembly where you set the breakpoint.

More Generically, you could do this:

1. Go to the breakpoint navigator.
2. Click the + button and choose "Add Exception Breakpoint"
3. Set Exception: to "Objective-C"
4. Set Break: to "On Throw"
5. Click "Done"

This may be more or less useful depending on your code.

See also the XCode 4 documentation result for "Adding an Exception Breakpoint"

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8422144/377384) answer shows you how to log the message you put in `NSAssert`. Very helpful for me.

Comment: Now I am using latter way with my own assertion macro: `EONIL_ASSERT(cond,msg...) {if(!(cond)){NSLog(msg);} NSCAssert((cond), @"Assertion failed.");}`

Comment: Since this is a breakpoint that stops execution at the beginning of the assertion handler, all you have to do is hit 'continue' and the app will go on and log the assertion as normal.

Comment: @Eonil I suscribe to the guidelines for assertions set out by Steve Maguire in the book "Writing Solid Code".  Debugging code is always in-addition-to, not instead-of, release code.

By mixing both release-version error handling and debug-version assertions, you are going against that advice.  It makes your code harder to understand because all you see is EONIL_ASSERT(release-error-condition, @"One-size-fits-all error message");

Comment: This is an amazingly helpful answer! I wonder why this behaviour is not enabled by default in Xcode...

Answer (score 0):

Assertions are automatically disabled, by default, in a Release build. If you want assertions to work, do a Debug build, or turn off the Other C Flags build setting where assertions are turned off in the Release build.